# ORDER BY <int or varchar>

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a query in a stored procedure which needs to be sorted by either an integer column or a `varchar` column, depending on one of the parameters passed to the procedure.

I have this as my `ORDER BY` clause:

```
...
ORDER BY 
CASE @ReportType 
    WHEN 1 THEN
        ItemName + SubItemName
    WHEN 2 THEN
        ItemName + SubItemName 
    WHEN 3 THEN
        SubItemName
    WHEN 4 THEN
        CONVERT(int,ItemCode)
    ELSE 
        ItemName
END
```

For clarity, my table structure is something like this (irrelevant columns omitted):

```
ItemName     ItemCode    SubItemName    SubItemCode
Apple        AA1         Fuji           FJ1
Apple        AA1         Gala           GL1
Chicquita    1 
DelMonte     2
Plantain     -1
Orange        OR1        Satsuma        SS3
Orange        OR1        Valencia       VL2
```

If I try to run the query with @ReportType as 1,2 or 4 everything works, but if I pass a 3, I get an error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Orange' to data type int.
```

I believe this is because every case in the `ORDER BY` clause has to have the same data type. I know I could convert everything to a varchar, but if I sort by `CONVERT(varchar,ItemCode)`, I get funky ordering:

```
Chicquita    1
Plantain     -1 
DelMonte     2
```

is it possible to sort by a varchar field in some cases, but an integer in other cases?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SMSS with SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `CASE` returns a single type.  So, just use multiple keys in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @ReportType IN (1, 2) THEN ItemName + SubItemName END),
         (CASE WHEN @ReportType = 3 THEN SubItemName END),
         (CASE WHEN @ReportType = 4 THEN CONVERT(int, ItemCode) END),
         ItemName
```

The `CASE` expressions have no `ELSE` clause, so they return `NULL` for non-matching values.